# How can I color alternate rows of an iron list

Tags: polymer

I have an iron list which contains rows of a query from the database.  I would like to color alternate rows so that they stand out.

My guess is that I want to put a class like "even" by computing something from the index. The put a `class$="[[calculatedValue]]"` in the row template.  I can then color the row based on the existence of the even class.

However I am confused about how to do this.  Any property I create within the hosting element is just that, ONE property. how do I extend that so that I have a calculation for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to declare a class as you can do this with simple CSS.

Eg.

```
.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red; /* color 'em red */
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: simple solutions are the best.  Thx

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly. Sometimes the colors are repeated because iron-list  reorders physical elements on the fly. See https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/269